# non deterministic way to generate random large numbers

Tags: random, numbers

What is the best non-deterministic way to generate large random numbers? I wrote a code to generate large numbers using a time function, but it is deterministic.

Comment: Build a device which samples background gamma radiation in the atmosphere and sub-samples bits from the resulting data. :-) Seriously, no computation will be non-deterministic without non-deterministic input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Secure random numbers in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083204/secure-random-numbers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux machines `/dev/urandom` is a source of non-deterministic random numbers.

Another technique is to download some non-random material from the internet (news articles, stock quotes, etc); compress them (using zip or somesuch); then encrypt them with good encryption software (such as AES).  The resulting stream of bytes is random (for most practical purposes).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator

Answer (score 1):

It's much safer to use a random number generator provided by your OS or your programming language.  It's really hard to write a random number generator that doesn't produce any discernable patterns.

And as drdwilcox said above, you can't have a truly non-deterministic random number generator unless you have truly random input, which requires some kind of hardware.