# Generating secure, random, Ascii encoded string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, cryptography

I want to generate a secure and ASCII encoded random nonce for my JavaScript program (it has to work in WebKit). Preferably, I want to use an off-the-shelf tool. So far, the only answers I found was this:
[Secure random numbers in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083204/secure-random-numbers-in-javascript)

The only problem with this is that the result is random, and I'm not sure how I can ASCII encode it without sacrificing security (i.e., making it less random).

Edit: Math.random() is not cryptographically secure, and window.crypto only generates values in multiples of a byte (ASCII values are 7 bits, so if the encoding mechanism is implemented naively, it would reduce the randomness).

Comment: An encoding does not change the randomness of the value it encodes.

Comment: I thought ASCII is 7 bit, window.crypto only generates values in multiples of a byte. My gut feeling tells me encoding it back to 7 bit  could decrease the randomness.

Comment: Math.random() is not cryptographically secure.

Comment: We can't offer a solution until you define what you mean be `secure`?

Comment: @EricChen if I generate a random integer between x and y and ask you to guess it, are you better able to guess it if I happen to express the number in a different way?

Comment: @kojiro - Yes, if you are using Math.random() I have a higher probability of guessing it since it's not a cryptographically secure pseudo-random generator.

Comment: @EricChen I'm talking about encodings, not about `Math.random()`.

Comment: @kojiri - How would you encode a 8 bits character to 7 bits? I don't think abandoning the last bit is secure. I'm not a crypto person but what I need to do requires a fully secure CSPRNG

Comment: @EricChen by using more than one character to encode it, not by truncating the value to a different value.

Comment: @EricChen If you're using a good PRNG, it doesn't matter if you truncate characters as long as you have enough bits in the end.  Using the first 4 bits of two 8 bit characters is just as random as using 8 bits from one character.

Comment: @kojiro - Ah sorry, I was being stupid. I see what you mean :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encode arbitrary byte arrays as Base64 to get pure ASCII.

Comment: As in… http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript