# Crypto.getRandomValues Implementation for IE9 and Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, cryptography, internet-explorer-9

I am looking for an implementation of crypto.getRandomValues to use it in the Internet Explorer 9 and Firefox. From my basic knowledge of JS/HTML this are not available in those browser.

any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083204/secure-random-numbers-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

The best example I can find is `alert(window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(2))[1])`. This will work great for firefox and chrome- but not IE. You'll have to use a third party library such as [Clipperz](https://www.clipperz.com/open_source/javascript_crypto_library/) and check to see its compatibility if you want randomness on all three.