# Insecure Randomness in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, random, fortify

In my JavaScript I'm using `var num = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);`.  It is working fine, but when I scan my code with the Fortify Static Code Analyzer, it reports an "Insecure Randomness" issue.

I know another method to generate random numbers is `window.crypto.random()`; but `window.crypto` is not supported in all browsers.

Can anybody explain how to fix this issue?

Comment: Do you really need a secure random generator?

Comment: Are you using this random number to generate a private key?  A password?  If not, I think your security software is being a little bit paranoid.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083204/secure-random-numbers-in-javascript

Comment: @scunliffe,yes i need secure random generator,could you please guide me.

Comment: @stderr,im generating random number one to nine.