# openpgp.js on wp8 error

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8, openpgp, openpgp.js

I'm using an [openPgpJs](http://www.openpgpjs.org/openpgpjs/doc/index.html) library in my app, created with Apache Cordova.

Here's the part of the code:

```
        var publicKey = openpgp.key.readArmored(_publicKey);
        openpgp.encryptMessage(publicKey.keys, text).then(function (pgpMessage) {
            // success
            callback(pgpMessage);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            // failure
            console.error(error);
        });
```

It works fine but not on WP8. If fails, 'cause `openpgp` var is undefined. In that library source there's such code at the very beginning:

```
!function (e) {
"object" == typeof exports ? module.exports = e() : "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(e) : "undefined" != typeof window ? window.openpgp = e() : "undefined" != typeof global ? global.openpgp = e() : "undefined" != typeof self && (self.openpgp = e())
```

}

so `openpgp` should be defined. How can I make it work?

*UPDATE*
I've added `var openpgp = window.openpgp;` and the error disappeared. Now it joust fails to encrypt message - and it's hard to debug, cause the library code is minified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for anyone who came here with the same problems.

1. Use `var openpgp = window.openpgp;` to avoid "undefined" error.
2. The next problem is inside `getRandomValues` function - there is an exception `No secure random number generator available.`. To avoid this error too I've changed the last (with exception) statement to

`var sjcl = window.sjcl;
        if (sjcl.random.isReady()) {
            var buf = new Uint8Array(1);
            bytes = sjcl.random.randomWords(buf.length);
            buf.set(bytes);
        }else{
            var bytes = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
                bytes.push(isaac.rand());
                buf.set(bytes);
            }
        }`

according to @ZeroG answer for this question: [Secure random numbers in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083204/secure-random-numbers-in-javascript)

Hope it can help someone =)