# Cryptographically secure array shuffle

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, cryptography, shuffle

I am trying to shuffle an array using a cryptographically secure source of entropy.

I found a similar question, regarding shuffling arrays here [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array). However almost all solutions make use of `Math.random`, which is not secure.
Unfortunately I do not have the reputation to comment/post on that question.

Here is the solution I came up with, which uses Durstenfeld shuffling paired with a CSPRNG for generating random integers in a given range (provided by [random-number-csprng](https://github.com/joepie91/node-random-number-csprng) lib).

```
const randomNumber = require("random-number-csprng");

async function secureShuffleArray(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = await randomNumber(0, i);
    const temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
}
```

Is this implementation correct and unbiased?

notes:

- for my purposes the array would contain at most ~100 elements
- running nodejs v6.10.3 LTS (transpiled)

Comment: You indeed can post on any question starting from reputation 1

Comment: @smnbbrv i tried, but it appears that the question is "protected" and requires at least reputation 10 to post an answer on ...

Comment: And because that is a good question you now earned 10 reputation ;)

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47194034/shuffling-a-poker-deck-in-javascript-with-window-crypto-getrandomvalues) has some interesting insights related to the topic.

Comment: @user3297291 yes, i've seen that post, and it indeed seems that my solution is conceptually identical to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47253709/2269027) which combines a few answers from different sources. At this point I believe my solution is likely correct, but it would be nice to have a consensus here as this seems like a fairly requested algorithm for nodejs (or potentially browserified javascript).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reviewing extensively, I have concluded that the solution is correct, being a verbatim implementation of the Durstenfeld shuffle.

However, the Durstenfeld / Fisher-Yates shuffle is only as random as it's RNG source. My solution depends on the [random-number-csprng](https://github.com/joepie91/node-random-number-csprng) CSPRNG lib, which uses `crypto.randomBytesAsync`, and is therefore cryptographically secure for most all purposes (see [How random is crypto#randomBytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43033412/how-random-is-cryptorandombytes)).

**UPDATE**: I have published a functionally equivalent yet more efficient version of this solution here [crypto-secure-shuffle](https://github.com/dhessler/crypto-secure-shuffle), also available as an npm package. Here is the relevant implementation:

```
const secureRandomInRange = require("random-number-csprng");

async function secureShuffle(array) {
    const promises = [];

    // asynchronously generate an array of random numbers using a CSPRNG
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        promises.push(secureRandomInRange(0, i));
    }

    const randomNumbers = await Promise.all(promises);

    // apply durstenfeld shuffle with previously generated random numbers
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = randomNumbers[array.length - i - 1];
        const temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }

    return array;
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding the relevant sections of code/etc. from the  link(s). Thank you.

Comment: @JDOaktown added a functional implementation, how's that?