# Can I choose a random image from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

Can i choose a random image from an array to display it on a button? when i click the button i want to move from the chosen image to the next one.

I want to do a puzzle game in javascript and the idea is to display the puzzle with random images, and when you click on a button the image changes to the next one, for example. The random one is "img/cableTriple4.png", but when i click i want it to be "img/cableTriple1.png", then number 2, 3, and then again 4...

```
const gridSize = 4;
const juegoTablero = [
    [1, 2, 2, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 1],
    [2, 3, 4, 3],
    [1, 0, 0, 2],
];

// Imagenes que uso para los botones del grid
const imageNames = {

    // CABLES RECTOS
    0: ["img/cableRecto1.png",
        "img/cableRecto1.png"],

    // BOMBILLAS
    1: ["img/bombilla1.png",
        "img/bombilla2.png",
        "img/bombilla3.png",
        "img/bombilla4.png"],

    // CABLES DOBLES
    2: ["img/cableDoble1.png",
        "img/cableDoble2.png",
        "img/cableDoble3.png",
        "img/cableDoble4.png"],

    // CABLES TRIPLES
    3: ["img/cableTriple1.png",
        "img/cableTriple2.png",
        "img/cableTriple3.png",
        "img/cableTriple4.png"],

    // CENTRO
    4: ["img/centro1.png",
        "img/centro2.png",
        "img/centro3.png",
        "img/centro4.png"]
}
```

Comment: gotta note that `imageNames` is not an array, is an object with arrays on every `key`. Meaning that in your game you have to choose which key you will get the images from first it seems and then get the random image on every click. But there are still several things that needs to be clarified. You mentioned you wanted random images to pop up but if your 1st image to pop up is 4, then 1, 2,3 and then 4 again, then that's not random because you needed all your images from the array to be picked before showing image 4 again and also what have you tried to achieve your results?

Comment: Sorry for my english. What i meant is that the first image i want it to be random, everytime I reload the page, but after the first one it has to follow the order. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

The array can be *shuffled* using a (secure) random number generator as input. The shuffle is usually implemented using Fisher-Yates, as can be seen when looking at the [main answer about shuffling an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2450954/589259) on StackOverflow. That's what's required if you want a well distributed result.

It may be that a cryptographically secure number generator is required for the added confidence in the result. An example that helpfully shuffles indices instead of the elements themselves can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50066925/589259). However, beware that it relies on a single person project. There are also a few other answers that are cryptographically secure in the main answer above.

Then you go through the shuffled array until it is exhausted then start over. If a `turn` is kept then you can use that as index (of the indices) modulo the size of the array, as in:

```
   imageRefIndex = randomImageIndices[turn % randomImageIndices.length];
   imageRef = orgImageRefArray[imageRefIndex];
```

In other words, the array is shuffled once and then looped over.

---

If the original order needs to be maintained it is important to first create a copy of the array before it is shuffled of course. If an array with indices is shuffled specific for this purpose then this is probably not required.

Comment: Please try to implement yourself, and put a comment down below if anything is not clear or if you get stuck, but try to debug your code yourself before asking!

Answer (score 0):

The first image will be random upon page reloads while the subsequent images will follow the order defined in the `imageNames` array. Adjust the category index (`3` in this case).

```
let isFirstImageRandom = true;
let currentImageIndex = 0;

function getRandomImage() {
let randomImage;

if (isFirstImageRandom) {
  // For the first image select randomly
 randomImage = imageNames[3][Math.floor(Math.random() * imageNames[3].length)];
    isFirstImageRandom = false;
  } else {
  // After the first image follow the order
  randomImage = imageNames[3][currentImageIndex];
  currentImageIndex = (currentImageIndex + 1) % imageNames[3].length;
 }
 buttonImage.src = randomImage;
}
```