# Javascript: Generate random integer of n bits

Tags: javascript, random, cryptography

I want to generate a 512 bit integer for a DH private key. I looked around but cant find any javascript resources that show generating a random int of specific length

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4083204/1820553

Comment: Generate 512 bits byte-by-byte (or word-by-word) and pack them into BigInt

Answer (score 1):

How about generating 16 random 32UInt as shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues). Theoretically, if you wanted the numbers all together, you could then do something like:

```
randomNumber = generatedArray.map((partialResult, value) => (partialResult << 32) + value));
```

However, be note the javascript `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is only 53 bits long.

#### Edit

As @SamMason commented, it should be `reduce` instead of `map`. Moreover, as the bit shift operator is only defined to work on 32bit values, we could just multiply by `2^32`:

```
randomNumber = generatedArray.reduce(
    (partialResult, value) => partialResult * Math.pow(2,32) + value)
);
```

Comment: isn't that `reduce` rather than `map`?  even then it doesn't do the right thing, intermediate values overflow and wrap around as the shift operator is defined to work on 32bit values

Comment: @SamMason True, it should be `reduce`. And thank you, I did not know about the 32bit limitation. I guess I could just multiply by `2^16`.

Comment: wouldn't that be 2**32 given that you talked about 32bit uints initially?  javascript also doesn't have arbitrary precision numbers, so this is going to be little better than doing `Math.random() * 2**512` (only a "little" because you might get a CSPRNG) but why generate 512 bits to throw away all but top ~54

Comment: Yes, it should be 2**32, thank you. I just pointed out this method would theretically work. However, as you mention, only ~54 bits could actually be used because of Javascript's precision limitation.