# Pick a random letter from string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, random

*This question is different from Take random letters out from a string because I am not trying to remove anything from the string.*

I'm trying to pick a random letter from a string in JavaScript using Math.floor(Math.random()* string.length) and a while loop. It needs to continually add new random letters to this string until a specified length.

My code is:

```
var emptyString = "";
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var getRandomLetter = alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
var randomLetter = getRandomLetter;

while (emptyString.length < 6) {
emptyString += randomLetter;
emptyString ++;
} 
console.log(emptyString);
```

Problems:
The output is the same letter 6 times: ex. pppppp

The random letter is generated from the string only once and then repeated until the specified length. I need it to generate random output for each letter: ex. pwezjm

I also noticed that if I do a second different while loop over the string it will generate the same output as the first loop: ex. pppppp

I thought it would at least generate a different random letter then the first loop but it does not. Why is that?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1497512/1516112

Comment: You are only generating one random letter and not changing it. Why should it change?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you should obtain the letter every time, but you do it just once.

```
var emptyString = "";
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

while (emptyString.length < 6) {
  emptyString += alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
} 
console.log(emptyString);
```

Also, not sure what you wanted to achieve with `emptyString++`, removing that, since `++` is the "increment by one" operator and you can't incremenent a string. I think the purpose was to have it as a counter for that while loop, but it's needless, since the counter is the string length already.

Comment: If this is being used for password generation, `Math.random()` should not be used, as it is not a cryptographically-secure random number generator. Instead, create a `new Uint32Array(6)`, populate it with random values using `window.crypto.getRandomValues(uintArray);` and then use those numbers to pick values out of the alphabet. It's slightly more complicated, but worlds more paranoid. :)

Answer (score 3):

Get the random character in a `loop`

In your example, you are obtaining random character from array only once hence there is no way you are going to get another random character in `while loop`

Also note that `emptyString++` will cause result as `NaN` as you are trying to post-increment the `string`

```js
var emptyString = "";
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

while (emptyString.length < 6) {
  emptyString += alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
}
console.log(emptyString);
```

Another tip, `alphabet.length` could be cached instead of asking for it every time in `while`

Comment: Now that it just duplicates my answer (not to say it was intentional), I don't think there's any need to have it.

Answer (score 2):

While those above are nice. I like shorter code.

```
const randomLetter = ('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz').split('')[(Math.floor(Math.random() * 26 ))];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `getRandomLetter` into a function, and reassign `randomLetter` inside the loop like this:

```js
var emptyString = "";
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
function getRandomLetter() {
  return alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
}
var randomLetter;

while (emptyString.length < 6) {
  randomLetter = getRandomLetter();
  emptyString += randomLetter;
} 
console.log(emptyString);
```

You also can't increment `emptyString`, since it is a string.