# Password(Including numerics,alphabets,8 words at least

Tags: react-native

Hope you're fine

I would like to have a regex that could give me a password including these specifications :

- numerics
- alphabets ( Uppercase and Lowercase )
- 8 words at least

thanks you in advance !

Comment: 8 _words_? Did you mean characters?

Comment: Regex will not give you a random string, it just checks the given string and returns the matched results. If you want to verify a given string includes your requirements you can use the @steve_pineapple 's answer. If you want to generate a password, you can use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16548229/5793132

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regular expression `(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.{8,})` to validate if...

- the password is 8 or more characters long (`(?=.{8,})`),
- if the password has at least one uppercase letter (`(?=.*[A-Z])`),
- if the password has at least one lowercase letter (`(?=.*[a-z])`) and
- contains at least one digit (`(?=.*[0-9])`).

The following function in JavaScript shows how you can use the regular expression to check if a password meets the requirements.You didn't mention what language you where using, but it should work in a other langauges (it worked in Python, Ruby, PHP, & Java).

```
function validate_password(password) {
  let check = /(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.{8,})/;
  if (password.match(check)) {
     console.log("Your password is strong.");
  } else {
    console.log("Meh, not so much.");
  }
}

validate_password("Password123"); // strong password
validate_password("OtherPassword"); // no numbers
validate_password("password123"); // no uppercase
validate_password("ToShort"); // to short
```

this [website](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/password-strength-checker-javascript/) has more details on password strength checking.

Comment: Such criteria of forcing a lower case, a upper case, a number and a symbol (or some combination of those) for passwords is obsolete and deprecated a few years ago, in favor for longer passwords, ideally randomly generated. In your example, what you deem a as strong password is, in fact, a **TERRIBLE** one, very likely to be cracked within seconds.